# adding json key names to a json values and changing key names

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json string that is in the format:

```
[
  {
   clientIDs:
         "WELL #6",
   analyteIDs:
         [
          "7440-62-2",
          "7440-28-0"
         ]
  }
]
```

I need to convert this to:

```
[
  {
   header:
         "WELL #6",
   items:
         [
          header: "7440-62-2",
          header: "7440-28-0"
         ]
  }
]
```

The values without a key name are throwing me off.

Comment: and what have you done so far?

Comment: You can't add keys if it is an array

Comment: Just change the brackets under `items` to curly braces

Comment: What @luekbaja is saying is correct, but you can make the the arrays into arrays of key value pairs.

Comment: @luekbaja he shouldn't do that, because then there would be duplicate keys. It should be an array. Neo, put curly braces around the header key value pairs that are within the items array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately js cannot store a key value arrays, instead you have to use an object storing key and value. So the closes result you can achieve is following:

```js
[
  {
   header:
         "WELL #6",
   items:
         [
          { header: "7440-62-2" },
          { header: "7440-28-0" }
         ]
  }
]
```

For that your steps will be following:

- Assuming you have an array of objects.
- Assuming the keys you want to change are static and will always exist in the objects

```js
 const myObjects = [
      {
       clientIDs:
             "WELL #6",
       analyteIDs:
             [
              "7440-62-2",
              "7440-28-0"
             ]
      }
    ]

    myObjects.map((myObj) => {
      myObj['header'] = myObj.clientIDs;
      myObj['items'] = myObj.analyteIDs.map((item) => {
        return { header: item }
      });
      
      // Keep in mind, if keys are dynamic and does not exist in some objects then this will fail
      delete myObj['clientIDs'];
      delete myObj['analyteIDs'];
    });

    console.log(myObjects);
```

Comment: It sets the key names but it's the array that's tripping me up

Comment: @Neovssmith I am sorry, I missed that part, I have updated the code

Comment: Okay thank you let me check it out and try to implement it this morning

Comment: Ohh thank you! I'm going to practice using/implementing this map method.!